# Intel pin: how to detect realloc size

Tags: c++, c, reverse-engineering, intel-pin

I have a following pin tool, say `trace.cpp` (exactly as is in a pin tool [manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/index.html)):

```
#include "pin.H"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Names of malloc and free */
/* ===================================================================== */
#if defined(TARGET_MAC)
#define MALLOC "_malloc"
#define FREE "_free"
#else
#define MALLOC "malloc"
#define FREE "free"
#endif

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Global Variables */
/* ===================================================================== */

std::ofstream TraceFile;

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Commandline Switches */
/* ===================================================================== */

KNOB<string> KnobOutputFile(KNOB_MODE_WRITEONCE, "pintool",
    "o", "malloctrace.out", "specify trace file name");

/* ===================================================================== */


/* ===================================================================== */
/* Analysis routines                                                     */
/* ===================================================================== */
 
VOID Arg1Before(CHAR * name, ADDRINT size)
{
    std::cout << name << "(" << size << ")" << endl;

}

VOID MallocAfter(ADDRINT ret)
{
    std::cout << "  returns " << ret << endl;
}


/* ===================================================================== */
/* Instrumentation routines                                              */
/* ===================================================================== */
   
VOID Image(IMG img, VOID *v)
{
    // Instrument the malloc() and free() functions.  Print the input argument
    // of each malloc() or free(), and the return value of malloc().
    //
    //  Find the malloc() function.
    RTN mallocRtn = RTN_FindByName(img, MALLOC);
    if (RTN_Valid(mallocRtn))
    {
        RTN_Open(mallocRtn);

        // Instrument malloc() to print the input argument value and the return value.
        RTN_InsertCall(mallocRtn, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)Arg1Before,
                       IARG_ADDRINT, MALLOC,
                       IARG_FUNCARG_ENTRYPOINT_VALUE, 0,
                       IARG_END);
        RTN_InsertCall(mallocRtn, IPOINT_AFTER, (AFUNPTR)MallocAfter,
                       IARG_FUNCRET_EXITPOINT_VALUE, IARG_END);

        RTN_Close(mallocRtn);
    }

    // Find the free() function.
    RTN freeRtn = RTN_FindByName(img, FREE);
    if (RTN_Valid(freeRtn))
    {
        RTN_Open(freeRtn);
        // Instrument free() to print the input argument value.
        RTN_InsertCall(freeRtn, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)Arg1Before,
                       IARG_ADDRINT, FREE,
                       IARG_FUNCARG_ENTRYPOINT_VALUE, 0,
                       IARG_END);
        RTN_Close(freeRtn);
    }
}

/* ===================================================================== */

VOID Fini(INT32 code, VOID *v)
{
    TraceFile.close();
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Print Help Message                                                    */
/* ===================================================================== */
   
INT32 Usage()
{
    cerr << "This tool produces a trace of calls to malloc." << endl;
    cerr << endl << KNOB_BASE::StringKnobSummary() << endl;
    return -1;
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Main                                                                  */
/* ===================================================================== */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Initialize pin & symbol manager
    PIN_InitSymbols();
    if( PIN_Init(argc,argv) )
    {
        return Usage();
    }
    
    // Write to a file since cout and cerr maybe closed by the application
    TraceFile.open(KnobOutputFile.Value().c_str());
    TraceFile << hex;
    TraceFile.setf(ios::showbase);
    
    // Register Image to be called to instrument functions.
    IMG_AddInstrumentFunction(Image, 0);
    PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);

    // Never returns
    PIN_StartProgram();
    
    return 0;
}
```

(The only variation is that it prints the instead of storing it in the output file)

I have a following c code example - `example.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A {
    int x[10];
    int y[1];
};

int main()
{
  struct A *ptr = calloc(1, sizeof(struct A));
  ptr->x[10] = 4;
  printf("%i\n", ptr->x[10]);
  ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(int));
  ptr->x[10] = 4;
  printf("%i\n", ptr->x[10]);
  free(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

When I run it with the pin tool, it produces the following output:

```
$ pin -t obj-intel64/trace.so -- ./example.o | tail
  returns 139865991781744
malloc(272)
  returns 139865991785984
malloc(44)
  returns 33456736
malloc(4096)
  returns 33456800
free(33456736)
4
4
```

Notice the couple of `malloc` calls:

```
malloc(44)
malloc(4096)
```

It detects the first one perfectly (notice calloc call in the c code), but it detects 4096 for realloc (correct me if I'm wrong here). But, I believe it supposed to detect 4 (sizeof int) instead.

Where am I going wrong? Is there any way by which the correct size can be detected (or maybe I am missing something here)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the trace tool to trace actual calls to `malloc` and `free`. You don't seem to be tracing calls to `calloc` and `realloc`, presumably on the assumption that those functions will eventually call `malloc`.

That's not necessarily true, though. For example, if `realloc` detects that the existing memory block is already sufficiently big to satisfy the request, it can just return its first argument without doing anything more, so you won't see any call to malloc. This is evidently what happened in your example, since your `realloc` call asks for less memory than was allocated by `calloc`, and we can see that it didn't do that here, since the address of `ptr` when `free` is called is the same as the block allocated by `calloc`.

If the existing allocation is much bigger than the request, `realloc` may choose to copy the block into a smaller allocation, possibly acquired with `malloc`. . But even if `realloc` does decide to reduce the size of the allocated memory, there is no guarantee that it wiil need a new allocation. On some implementations, it is possible to split the existing block,  adding the unneeded part to the free list. That won't involve a call to either `free` or `malloc`.

So if the `malloc(4096)` doesn't come from the `realloc`, where does it come from? Most likely,  the answer is that `malloc` was called from the standard library. For example, `printf` might have  noticed that it needs to allocate an output buffer for `stdout`, so it calls `malloc` to get some memory.

In short, you probably need to trace all memory management functions to get a clear idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I made following changes in the tool:

```
#include "pin.H"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Names of malloc and free */
/* ===================================================================== */
#if defined(TARGET_MAC)
#define MALLOC "_malloc"
#define FREE "_free"
#else
#define MALLOC "malloc"
#define FREE "free"
#endif

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Global Variables */
/* ===================================================================== */

std::ofstream TraceFile;

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Commandline Switches */
/* ===================================================================== */

KNOB<string> KnobOutputFile(KNOB_MODE_WRITEONCE, "pintool",
    "o", "malloctrace.out", "specify trace file name");

/* ===================================================================== */


/* ===================================================================== */
/* Analysis routines                                                     */
/* ===================================================================== */

VOID Arg1Before(CHAR * name, ADDRINT addr, ADDRINT size, ADDRINT return_ip)
{
    std::cout << name << " : " << addr << "(" << size << ")" << " : " << return_ip << endl;

}

VOID MallocAfter(ADDRINT ret)
{
    std::cout << "  returns " << ret << endl;
}


/* ===================================================================== */
/* Instrumentation routines                                              */
/* ===================================================================== */

VOID Image(IMG img, VOID *v)
{
    // Instrument the malloc() and free() functions.  Print the input argument
    // of each malloc() or free(), and the return value of malloc().
    //
    //  Find the malloc() function.
    RTN mallocRtn = RTN_FindByName(img, "realloc");
    if (RTN_Valid(mallocRtn))
    {
        RTN_Open(mallocRtn);

        // Instrument malloc() to print the input argument value and the return value.
        RTN_InsertCall(mallocRtn, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)Arg1Before,
                       IARG_ADDRINT, "realloc",
                       IARG_FUNCARG_ENTRYPOINT_VALUE, 0,
                       IARG_FUNCARG_ENTRYPOINT_VALUE, 1,
                       IARG_END);
        RTN_InsertCall(mallocRtn, IPOINT_AFTER, (AFUNPTR)MallocAfter,
                       IARG_FUNCRET_EXITPOINT_VALUE, IARG_END);

        RTN_Close(mallocRtn);
    }

    // Find the free() function.
    RTN freeRtn = RTN_FindByName(img, FREE);
    if (RTN_Valid(freeRtn))
    {
        RTN_Open(freeRtn);
        // Instrument free() to print the input argument value.
        RTN_InsertCall(freeRtn, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)Arg1Before,
                       IARG_ADDRINT, FREE,
                       IARG_FUNCARG_ENTRYPOINT_VALUE, 0,
                       IARG_END);
        RTN_Close(freeRtn);
    }
}

/* ===================================================================== */

VOID Fini(INT32 code, VOID *v)
{
    TraceFile.close();
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Print Help Message                                                    */
/* ===================================================================== */

INT32 Usage()
{
    cerr << "This tool produces a trace of calls to malloc." << endl;
    cerr << endl << KNOB_BASE::StringKnobSummary() << endl;
    return -1;
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Main                                                                  */
/* ===================================================================== */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Initialize pin & symbol manager
    PIN_InitSymbols();
    if( PIN_Init(argc,argv) )
    {
        return Usage();
    }

    // Write to a file since cout and cerr maybe closed by the application
    TraceFile.open(KnobOutputFile.Value().c_str());
    TraceFile << hex;
    TraceFile.setf(ios::showbase);

    // Register Image to be called to instrument functions.
    IMG_AddInstrumentFunction(Image, 0);
    PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);

    // Never returns
    PIN_StartProgram();

    return 0;
}
```

I found the routine name by "realloc", instead of "malloc" and then passed:

```
IARG_FUNCARG_ENTRYPOINT_VALUE, 0,
IARG_FUNCARG_ENTRYPOINT_VALUE, 1,
```

to the function `Arg1Before`, to detect the two arguments of the `realloc` function call.

And then in the `Arg1Before` function:

```
VOID Arg1Before(CHAR * name, ADDRINT addr, ADDRINT size, ADDRINT return_ip)
```

Here, `size` is the size of memory allocated, `addr` is the address of the pointer and `return_ip` is the address of the return instruction pointer.